# ReactJS: Detect which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this simple requirement that detects which button is clicked.  The code is as below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    ['Hotel 1A', ['A']],
    ['Hotel 1B', ['B']],
  ]

  const [sameText, setSameText] = useState(false)

  const changeText = (e: any, index: number, item: any) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    console.log(index)
    console.log(item)

    if ((item[e.target.value] == item[index])) {
      setSameText(true)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='mx-auto'>
      <div className='flex p-16'>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div className='mx-16' key={index}>
            <div className='p-12'>
              <button onClick={(e) => changeText(e, index, item)} value={index}>
                {item[0]}
              </button>
              <div>{sameText ? 'C' : item[1][0]}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The code above will display text as below:

```
Hotel 1A      Hotel 1B
A             B
```

If I click on Hotel 1A, I have like 'A' to be changed to 'C' and if I click on Hotel 1B, only 'B' will change to 'C'.  I thought I need to get the value of the button but I could not get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you are assigning `item[index]` to `item[e.target.value]` in if check , change `=` too `===`
- Second, you have one state for both buttons, you have to keep 1 value for each button

if you just want to make that code work here is an working example:

```
const [sameText, setSameText] = useState([false, false]);

  const changeText = (e: any, index: number, item: any) => {
    if (item[e.target.value] === item[index]) {
      const newState = [...sameText];
      newState[index] = true;
      setSameText(newState);
    }
  };
```

and if check

```
<div>{sameText[index] ? 'C' : item[1][0]}<div/>
```

For N hotels you can use that:

```
const [clickedHotel, setClickedHotel] = useState(
    null,
  );

  const changeText = (e: any, index: number, item: any) => {
    if (item[e.target.value] === item[index]) {
      setClickedHotel(index);
    }
  };
```

and

```
<div>{clickedHotel === index ? 'C' : item[1][0]}</div>
```

Comment: thx for pointing that out, I have edited the question.

Comment: I can't use [false, false] as it can be a long list of hotels

Comment: gimmie a sec, will write working example for N hotels

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state for each button and change the state on click. Your buttons are rendered based on the button state

For example:

1. introduce `const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(data);`
2. `map` over `buttonState` instead of `data`
3. in `changeText()` change the state as you want by calling `setButtonState()`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the nested arrays in the items array

You are almost there and you have done it correctly `console.log(item[1][0])` will give you the

But there is one more thing you need to do is following:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    ['Hotel 1A', ['A']],
    ['Hotel 1B', ['B']],
  ]

  const [sameText, setSameText] = useState(false)

  const changeText = (e: any, index: number, item: any) => {
    console.log(item[1][0])

    // if ((item[e.target.value] = item[index])) {
    //   setSameText(true)
    // }
  }
  return (
    <div className='mx-auto'>
      <div className='flex p-16'>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div className='mx-16' key={index}>
            <div className='p-12'>
              <button onClick={(e) => changeText(e, index, item)} value={index}>
                {item[0]}
              </button>
              <div>{sameText ? 'C' : item[1][0]}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```